# Instagram API - Next_url not working

Tags: php, instagram-api

Guys i'm working around the Instagram PHP API to get all images/posts for a specific tag in Instagram.

Here is my code:

```
<?PHP
 function callInstagram($url)
    {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2
    ));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
    }

    $tag = "bulgaria";
    $client_id = "1e0f576fbdb44e299924a93cace24507";
    $Next_URL = $_GET["nexturl"];
    if($Next_URL == ""){
    $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/'.$tag.'/media/recent?client_id='.$client_id.'&count=24';
    } else {
    $url =  $Next_URL;
    }
    $inst_stream = callInstagram($url);
    $results = json_decode($inst_stream, true);
    $maxid = $results['pagination']['next_max_id'];
    $nexturl = $results['pagination']['next_url'];
    //Now parse through the $results array to display your results... 
    foreach($results['data'] as $item){
        $image_link = $item['images']['thumbnail']['url'];
        $Profile_name = $item['user']['username'];

        echo '<div style="display:block;float:left;">'.$Profile_name.' <br> <img src="'.$image_link.'" /></div>';
    }

    echo "<div style='display:block;width:100%;clear:both;'>MaxID: $maxid <br>NextURL: <a href='?nexturl=$nexturl'>Next images</a> <br>N: $Next_URL</div>";
```

When the page is loaded for first there on `Next images` i get the following a href link `http://myweb.com/instagram?nexturl=https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/bulgaria/media/recent?count=24&client_id=1e0f576fbdb44e299924a93cace24507&max_tag_id=1427645740441335`

When i click on the `Next images` and the page is opened i get no images loaded like they were in the first loading.

Please copy the code and test it.

I want to make some kind of pagination so when i click on `Next images` the next set of 24 images with the tag `bulgaria` to be loaded at the page.

Can you please tell me where is my mistake ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode `$nexturl` string using `urlencode()` function.

You can replace the last line in your code with the following two lines:

```
$nextUrlEncoded = urlencode($nexturl);
echo "<div style='display:block;width:100%;clear:both;'>MaxID: $maxid <br>NextURL: <a href='?nexturl=$nextUrlEncoded'>Next images</a> <br>N: $Next_URL</div>";
```